# Sending list of files from server to client's JPanel

Tags: java, swing, client-server

Brief explanation :

My application sends files from the server side to the client side and the client chooses the name of the file and the extension however , in order for the client to see the list of files I have written a method that would list the files available on the server.

Though the method is working but I need to send the file names to the client and to insert them in a `JPanel` and List them there, so that the user could choose which file he wants .

Here is my method on the server side:

```
 public static void listfile() {

 String path = "C:/SAVE"; 

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
  {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
   {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
   System.out.println(files);
      }
  }
    }
```

How can I modify it so that it sends the list of files to the client upon call.

Comment: What have you tried / thought of so far? And how are you connected to the Client? Is it a permantent TCP connection for example?

Comment: how do you communicate with server?

Comment: it is a tcp connection socket

Comment: then you should serialize array of files and send them as a plain string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tcp connections, your server could implement a command called "listFiles". When it receives this command, it should send to the client the file listing.

The client should connect to the server, send the command "listFiles", read in the list of files sent by the server and display it on its JPanel.

Let's say you have a simple single threaded server in the following pattern:

```
class Server
{
    public void run()
    {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(<portno>);

        Socket socket = server.accept();

        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream(); // for reading the command

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); // for writing out the list

        // Now read the argument from in, say the result is in variable "cmd"

        if("listFiles".equals(cmd))
        {
            // invoke your list files logic, and instead of writing to the console
            // write it to out
        }
    }
}
```

Your client should follow the below pattern:

```
class Client
{
    public void getList()
    {
        Socket client = new Socket(<portno>);
        InputStream in = client.getInputStream(); // to read in the file list
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream(); // to send the listFiles command

        // Write the  listFiles command to out

        // Read in the list of files from in

        // Update your JPanel with the list
    }
}
```

I have left out the actual reading and writing from/to the sockets, but you wil get the idea.

Comment: this is wht i am not getting can u help coding wise please